# Laravel - cannot send message without a sender address

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I have trouble with sending multiple jobs in Laravel.

Sometimes it working all right.

Sometimes I got this message `cannot send message without a sender address` in `failed_job` table and just 1 one worked.

Sometimes both not working.

And that's in my local but on the server it not working at all.

I'm trying to clear cache, config, everything but it just not work at all.

And I don't think it because my setting on `.env` cause it not always got errors.

Just sometimes got errors sometimes work.

The most common error is 1 working and 1 not.

[image]
[image]

It just running 1 job and 1 job will throw fail in `failed_job` table

**JOBS**

```php
class SendContactContentEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Batchable, Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;
    public $emails;
    public $tries = 5;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param array $_data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $_data
    )
    {
        $this->data = $_data;
        $this->emails = config('email.admin');
    }
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $content = new ContactContentEmail($this->data);
        if (!empty($this->emails)){
            foreach ($this->emails as $email){
                Mail::to($email)->send($content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```php
class SendContactEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Batchable, Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $email_address;
    public $tries = 5;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param string $_email_address
     */
    public function __construct(
        string $_email_address
    )
    {
        $this->email_address = $_email_address;
    }
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = new ContactEmail();
        Mail::to($this->email_address)->send($email);
    }
}
```

**Mails**

```
class ContactContentEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $data;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($_data)
    {
        $this->data = $_data;
    }
    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('contact.emails.contact_content')->with([
                'data' => $this->data
            ]);
    }
}
```

```
class ContactEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('contact.emails.contact');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function send(ContactFormRequest $request){
     $data = $request->validated();
     dispatch(new SendContactContentEmail($data));
     dispatch(new SendContactEmail($data['mail_address']));
}
```

**Config Email**

```
return [
    'admin' => [
        'kuriyama' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
        'negishi' => 'aaaa@gmail.com',
    ]
];
```

**ENV**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=contact@xxx.com.vn
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxx@xxx.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Try setting `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` in your `.env` file

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu I already have it. I don't think my setting is wrong. Because it not always error. it working sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Can you call this command?

```
php artisan config:cache
```